LED Cathode Reverse Voltage Question
In normal use LED I/O is either 0 V (sank to GND) or 15 V or floating. When LED I/O is 0 V the red led is shining, when it's 15 V, then the blue LED is shining. When it's floating both are on, more or less, but this is not a problem. Everything is working properly.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
My question is what could happen if I apply 27 V instead of 15 V to LED I/O?
The voltage difference between the red LED cathode and its anode is +- 11 V. However, R11's 22 kΩ is drastically reducing the reverse current. After a test of a few seconds, the LEDs didn't seem damaged. But is it good on the long term, with very long durations?
And can the 27 V interfere with the linear voltage regulators?
I'm using this double colour led. The blue led is 3.9 V, the red LED is 2.4 V. Forward current max is 20 mA. Reverse voltage max is 5 V.

The reverse voltage specification in the datasheet is for every produced led over the full temperature range. Just because one led didn't get damaged at room temperature, doesn't mean a later one from a different batch will be able to stand it.

Neither the schematic nor the picture of the schematic  show on my computer. Do you see them?

The picture and schematic work from here. Try accessing the question from a different network or opening them in a new tab to capture the error to report them to meta.stackexchange.com

Now, both the schematic and the picture appear fine. Thanks. Maybe it takes some time (by moderators?) to be approved.

@Fredled - Hi, I just saw your comments by chance - re: "Maybe it takes some time (by moderators?) to be approved.". No, there is no moderator approval delay when you are editing your own question. As Ferrybig mentioned, the network being used can be relevant, as there seem to be some intermittent issues (not fully solved AFAIK) where images can be accessible via network/ISP X but not via network/ISP Y. See this Meta.SE question for an example of what some people have reported. || TL;DR I just wanted to let you there wasn't a mod approval delay.

You don't tell us anything about the source of signal LEDIO. If it can source and sink current, then powering this whole thing from +27V instead of +15V makes all your problems go away. For better answers, show us the circuitry responsible for LEDIO.

First of all, I don't see the 27V on LED I/O interfering with the voltage regulators.
Then, let's see what could happen to the LED if we apply 27V on LED I/O.
We would have \$27V - 15V = 12V\$ on R11 in series with LED2.
Without a precise model or characteristics for the LED, we have to approximate and iterate a bit to determine the current going through it.
The datasheet tells us that at a reverse bias \$V_{LED}=5V\$, there should be a reverse current \$I_{LED}=100µA\$. With a 22k resistor, that gives us \$V_R=2.2V\$ on R11, meaning \$V_{LED} + V_R = 7.2V < 12V\$, not good enough.
We thus have to assume a higher reverse voltage on the LED and a higher reverse current. If we assume \$V_{LED} = 8V\$, \$I_{LED}=200µA\$, then \$V_R=22k \times 200µ = 4.4V\$, bringing us closer to the objective: \$V_{LED} + V_R = 12.4V \approx 12V\$.
Now looking at the power dissipation of the LED, the datasheet tells us 48mW. With our current figures, we're at \$P_{LED} = 8 \times 200µ = 1.6mW\$, which looks OK.
However, I think the 22k resistors are to high a value to let enough current go through the LEDs to light them up. For LED2, if you want 10mA at 1.9V (see datasheet) and a 15V supply, you would only need 1.31\$k\Omega\$. This means that the above calculation are off, the reverse current through the LED can get much higher and it could go poof on the longer term. If you have a physical version of the circuit, take some measurement to check the power dissipated by the LED.
I would also suggest looking into adding a 15V zener diode in parallel with LED1 to make sure the node between the two LEDs does not climb significantly past 15V.

Thank for your answer. The LED's are OK with 22K. They are bright enough for the application. Yes, I could add a Zener or a diode in series with LED2. The question is should I do it? I don;t understand your calculation VLED + VR = 7.2V < 12V.. Why do you add VLED and VR?

When you apply +27V to LEDIO, LED2 will be strongly reverse biased, and begin to conduct current in the wrong direction, eventually damaging it. Also, depending on what else is connected to the +15V regulator output, this will cause that regulator to sink current instead of source it, and prevent it from regulating properly. You'll need to address this. The simplest solution to both issues is to add a regular diode in that path, to prevent reverse current:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I've removed R12, because I don't know what it does (it seems redundant). D20 blocks reverse current through LED2. While not strictly necessary, I've added R20 to bypass D20's small leakage current around LED2, instead of through it.
LED1 seems to be safe, as long as the current it passes is safe, which is completely dependent on R9 and the potential at LEDIO. Consider increasing R9 (as shown) to have LED1 pass a similar amount of current when LEDIO is +27V as LED2 does when LEDIO is 0V.
I don't see the need for a zener diode to protect LED1, but if you did use one, it would look something like this:

simulate this circuit
R9 is back to 22kΩ, because there's now 15V across the LED/resistor pair, just like LED2.

Thanks for the suggestions. So, according to you D20 is necessary to prevent damage or other problems in the long term. The problem with R20 is that it reduces the current and voltage at LED2's anode. If the reverse leakage current is small enough, I'd prefer not to add it.  Or put a second diode instead from LED2's cathode to anode. The Zener is not needed, but if you add it for some reason, you could simply put one resistor on LED1's anode side and on D21 cathode side.

The Zener can be used without the diode D20 if you put R11 between LEDIO and LED2's cathode, and LED4's cathode directly connected to LED1's anode. Then R11 would serve as a regulator for both LEDs and for limiting the current to the Zener. R9, R20 and R21 can be scrapped.

@Fredled Forget R20 then, that's fine. The only critical thing to address is LED2 reverse breakdown, and as long as you take care of that (with D20) you're good. my suggestions here are just minor modifications to your original design, but there might be a dozen other very different approaches, of which your last comment seems to be one. Widen the scope of your original question by appending this other idea as a schematic (because I can't see it in my head), and request for comments.
